# Handling Unhandled Exception in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to handle any unhandled exception thrown in the application using this:

The xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Updater.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
             DispatcherUnhandledException="UnhandledException"
             >
```

The code:

```
private void UnhandledException(object sender,    DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var time = DateTime.Now;
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\exps.csv", string.Format("{0},{1}", time, e.Exception.Message));
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\sts.txt", time + ":\n" + e.Exception.StackTrace + "\n");
    e.Handled = false; //we want the user to experience the crash
}
```

But the dispatcher not working and not execute when the application throw exception.

Comment: Why can't you surround your dangerous code with try catch?

Comment: `DispatcherUnhandledException` will catch the unhandled exception only from the UIThread.   Unhandled exception on other threads won't be caught here.

Comment: It is critical to keep the app running all the time. That is why I need to handled unpredicted exception @FCin

Comment: @Gopichandar I tried also to throw exception on the main ui, it was not handled by the DispatcherUnhandledException